# customed transformer in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I tried to make my pipe and add my customed transformer as follow:

```
class DataFrameSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, attribute_names):
        self.attribute_names = attribute_names
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        return X[list(self.attribute_names)]
```

and

```
class DummyTransform(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self):
        return None

    def transform(self, X):
        return pd.get_dummies(X).values

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
```

but when i do:
    RF=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,oob_score=True,random_state=3)

```
pipe= Pipeline(steps=[
    ('Selector', DataFrameSelector(attribute_names=('lat','long','type'))),   # selects the second and 4th column      
    ('Encoder', DummyTransform() ) 
    ('clf',RF)
    ])
rforest=pipe.fit(X_train,Y_train)
```

I have the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-168-108f5c7552a0> in <module>()
      4     ('Selector', DataFrameSelector(attribute_names=('lat','long','type'))),   # selects the second and 4th column
      5     ('Encoder', DummyTransform() )
----> 6     ('clf',RF)
      7     ])
      8 rforest=pipe.fit(X_train,Y_train)

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Why ???

PS: strangely this one works:

```
RF=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,oob_score=True,random_state=3)

pipe= Pipeline(steps=[
    ('Selector', DataFrameSelector(attribute_names=('lat','long','type'))),   # selects the second and 4th column      
    ('Encoder', DummyTransform() ) 
    #('clf',DecisionTreeClassifier())
    ])
X=pipe.fit_transform(X_train,Y_train)
RF.fit(X,Y_train)
```

Edit: RF stand for this line of code
    RF=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,oob_score=True,random_state=3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a missing a comma one line above your error, at the end, it worked when you commented it because the comma was missing on the last item